# Unable to Access IAM AWS Service Endpoint in a private subnet using a Private Link of VPC Endpoint

Tags: amazon-iam, amazon-vpc, aws-java-sdk-2.x, aws-private-link

We're trying to access AWS Services from a private subnet in a VPC using a VPC endpoint or Private Link. We're trying to avoid adding a NAT gateway on the private subnet.

```
We created/added a VPC Endpoints (i.e. AWS Service for EC2 and S3)
com.amazonaws.us-east-2.ec2
com.amazonaws.us-east-2.s3

But we're not able to access something like com.amazonaws.us-east-2.iam; is there an iam endpoint or is this supported or is there any workaround
for us to use iam via VPC Endpoint on us-east-2?
```

Here's the error we're getting when we use the latest version of Java AWS SDK to get ec2 instance attached iam role programatically

> org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to
> iam.amazonaws.com:443 [iam.amazonaws.com/

Thanks for any information you can provide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of May 2022, VPC endpoint for IAM is not supported. You'd have to connect to IAM via internet. Or as a workaround, you can do IAM actions in CloudFormation.

Comment: Thanks for that quick answer, now I can search about that workaround in cloudformation.  Cheers =)

Comment: @bherto39 Absolutely :)

Comment: Here is the list of currently supported AWS resources: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/aws-services-privatelink-support.html It's a shame IAM is not part of it. 

Comment: @jellycsc So , for further clarification, this would mean a VPC endpoint for cloudformation and using a cloudformation template that creates IAM Roles and policies, for example, would work?

Comment: @SebastianA Yes, that would work.